# ISS No muestra conexiones ni sitios

Tags: windows, iis, server, microsoft

Cuando quiero acceder a IIS no me muestra ningún sitio al momento de abrirlo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he entrado anteriormente a la sección de "Activar o desactivar caracteristicas de windows" y he activado el paquete de "Internet Informations Services" con lo necesario para que teoricamente funcionara,tambien note que en la direccion de Inetpub cuando lo abro, no me manda al navegador como Localhost si no que me abre el IIS directamente con la ruta del archivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de la misma manera, intentando poner esta Url en mi navegador "https://localhost" no me muestra nada relacionado a IIS, tampoco tengo otras aplicaciones corriendo en el puerto 80, he revisado tambien en los servicios locales que tengo actualmente y no me aparece el servicio de "Servicio de administración de IIS"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aunque la carpeta de Inetpub en mi Disco C: si aparece, tengo Windows 11 y no tengo ninguna otra aplicación usando el puerto 80